# Reducing video file size using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have an mp4 video file, which is about five minuttes long, but the file size is about 4 GB.
Here is the information ffmpeg gives about the video stream:
Video: h264 (High), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)

So, what is the best way to reduce the file size to about 100-200 MB without losing too much quality?

Answer (score -1):

You can reduce the resolution to Full HD for example 1920 x 1080

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "scale=1920:1080" output.mp4